# Protected методы в интерфейсах Java 9

Tags: java, java-9

Появятся ли `protected`/`package-private` методы в интерфейсах Java 9 или добавят только `private`?

Comment: Java 9 уже вышла, надо говорить "появились ли protected методы", а не "появятся".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Как видно из [источника](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/whatsnew/toc.htm#JSNEW-GUID-825576B5-203C-4C8D-85E5-FFDA4CA0B346) добавили только `private` методы

Comment: А какое-то объяснение есть, почему нельзя сразу добавить остальные модификаторы? То есть что это может сломать?

Comment: Идея приватных методов в интерфейсах - только переиспользовать код в нескольких default-методах, не публикуя его наружу.

Comment: @VictorKhovanskiy `package-private` не получится добавить, потому что методы без модификаторов в интерфейсах по умолчанию `public` (пункт 6.6.1 спеки).